# .shp file for Dubai International Airport

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, shapefile

I am creating a ssrs report that contains a map. However, I only want it to display for Dubai International Airport. Does anyone know where I can find a .shp file for this?

Would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: In terms of what .shp files or what sites?

Comment: All things which you have tried and didn't work so community brains could pick up from where you left.

Comment: I have tried a few sites and .shp files but all I want is to have a .shp file of Dubai Airport. I've tried a world view, UAE view but it's not something I'm looking for. Just want a view of Dubai International Airport.

Comment: Seems to me that ssrs maps are extremely static. However I found a different solution by using the url in a string with some extra code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as though maps within ssrs are extremely static so the solution I have found is to use an image and set a url with string to display the are I would like